# Libreoffice equation does not get saved in xlsx

Tags: microsoft-office, libreoffice-calc

If I create equations in a LibreOffice Calc document, and save it as xlsx it wont get saved.

Is there a way to create compatible equations in the first place or to convert them to Microsoft Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two choices,

1. Save as .xsl (not .xslx) and any version of Excel should be able to read it.
2. Save as .ods (OpenDocument Spreadsheet) and open with Microsoft Office Excel 2013 (not 2010 or earlier), since there is common formula support at that level.
3. Something else to try is to do (2) and put the document on Microsoft SkyDrive.  This may allows more download cases for Excel users, although not all features of LibreOffice Calc and Office Excel are preserved this way.  It depends on how complicated the rest of the spreadsheet is.  It is another, experimental, possibility.

Comment: saving as .xsl wont save equations as well.
i did save as xslx and then added the equations in M:Office myself. this was a temp fix. thanks for your suggesstions!
PS: i only have M:O 10 and earlier.